# ajax post returning string instead of json object

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, parse-platform

My code returns dataType object in PHP but when I am calling the same function using AJAX it returns the datatype to me as string. I want the data type to be a JSON object.

**PHP code**:

```
$result = $manualRequest->getUser($_POST['phonenumber']);

print_r($result);
```

This is actually a parsed database object

**AJAX code**:

```
function getCustomer() {
        var callerNumber = $('#caller_number').val();
        var data = {
            'phonenumber': callerNumber
        };
        var url = "customerRequest.php";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

I am getting the desired result but I want the JSON object and not the string.

Comment: `$manualRequest->getUser($_POST['phonenumber']);`  what does it return

Comment: `print(json_encode($result))`

Answer (score 1):

`print_r` doesn't generally return **valid** JSON, you want to do

```
$result = $manualRequest->getUser($_POST['phonenumber']);
echo json_encode( $result );
```

As long as it's valid JSON, and the `dataType` is set to `json`, jQuery will parse it as such, anything else should result in a "parse error" in your ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can use JSON.parse method to parse your string JSON to JSON object.

The documentation of this method: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: I am actually returning a PARSE( an MBASS ) Object from php and when I am trying what you told I am getting the below error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (startrequest.php:2012)
    at Function.handleSuccess (jquery-ui.min.js:142)

Comment: Oh, ok I see. It seem your PHP don't send the response to JSON format. I think you can use the solution of Željko Krnjić. you have to set your response header with the correct format: header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8'); and use json.encode method to respond with a formated JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

In php file add:

```
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($result);
```

instead of `print_r($result);`

Comment: in your javascript file, change line console.log(result) to console.log(JSON.parse(result));

Comment: This is giving me the below error   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at Object.success (startrequest.php:2012) at Function.handleSuccess (jquery-ui.min.js:142)

Comment: Ok, use console.log(result) (without JSON.parse) and paste me the result. Are you sure it isn't JSON already?

Comment: I am doing console.log(typeof(result)) and it is giving me string

Comment: just paste the result of console.log(result) here without typeof... i want to see how does the json or string you get as output looks like... you can also paste the output to jsonlint.com and see if it is a valid json..

Comment: Thanks for guiding me.  I was not getting valid JSON so I fetched the individual fields and made a json object and then returned it and my issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

If you want pretty JSON

```
$result = $manualRequest->getUser($_POST['phonenumber']);
echo json_encode($result , JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
```

**Edit**

```js
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: data,
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
})
  .done(function () {
    console.log("success");
  })
  .fail(function () {
    console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function () {
    console.log("complete");
  });
```